Get the absolute date difference
I have a simple SQL query shown below. If you look at scenario 1, the difference between dates in 1 month and that is correct (because Oct 5th - Sep 5th).
However, when you look at scenario 2, the difference between dates in still showing as 1. But it should be 0 (because Oct 4th - Sep 5th is still not 1 month).
Can we make sure the scenario 2 shows as 0?
Scenario 1
select 
    datediff(month, convert(datetime, '05-09-24', 5), convert(datetime, '05-10-24', 5))


1

Scenario 2
select 
    datediff(month, convert(datetime, '05-09-24', 5), convert(datetime, '04-10-24', 5))


1


The second value is correct; DATEDIFF tells you how many ticks have occured, not if that many have passed. DATEDIFF(YEAR,'20231232 23:59:59','20240101 00:00:00') is 1, because, even though only 1 second has passed, they are in different years.

Not that way.  What DATEDIFF does here is extract the year and month from the two dates and compute the difference.  Computing delta months the way you describe it is difficult, because the length of a month varies.  You can extract the month and the day separately and compare them.

DATEDIFF computes the number of boundaries crossed for the given type. So Sep 2 to Aug 31 is two days, but will still be one full month because it crosses the boundary. Also, for historical reasons, your date literals for date-only values (no time component) when writing t-sql should use the yyyyMMdd format (no dashes). Then you can also safely use cast() instead of convert()

"But it should be 0 (because Oct 4th - Sep 5th is still not 1 month)" Well, you specify the parameter as MONTH.  Oct - Sep = 1, so it is correct.

If you only care about dates (and not times) you can use the expression:
DATEDIFF(month, date1, date2)
    - CASE WHEN DAY(date1) > DAY(date2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

If you care about time and consider the difference between 2024-07-15 16:44:30 to 2024-08-15 16:44:29 to be less than one month (by one second), you can use the following:
DATEDIFF(month, datetime1, datetime2)
    - CASE WHEN DAY(datetime1) > DAY(datetime2)
                OR (
                    DAY(datetime1) = DAY(datetime2)
                    AND CAST(datetime1 AS TIME) > CAST(datetime2 AS TIME
                )
           THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

or alternately:
DATEDIFF(month, datetime1, datetime2)
    - CASE WHEN DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, datetime1, datetime2), datetime1)
           > datetime2
           THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

Each will adjust the month difference down by 1 if the first date/time is later in the month than the second date/time.
Note that for near-end-of-month start date/times where the ending months are shorter, the month will not be credited until the date rolls over to the 1st of the following month. For example:

2024-01-31 16:45 to 2024-02-29 23:59 is considered 0 months.
2024-01-31 16:45 to 2024-03-01 00:00 is considered 1 month.

Sample results:



datetime1
datetime2
comment
DiffRaw
Diff1
Diff2




2024-09-05 00:00
2024-10-05 00:00
1 month
1
1
1


2024-09-05 00:00
2024-10-04 00:00
1 day short of 1 month = 0 months
1
0
0


2024-09-05 00:00
2024-12-04 00:00
1 day short of 3 month = 2 months
3
2
2


2024-09-05 00:00
2024-12-05 00:00
3 months
3
3
3


2024-09-05 00:00
2024-12-31 00:00
3 months, 26 days
3
3
3


2024-09-05 00:00
2025-01-01 00:00
3 months, 27 days
4
3
3


2023-12-31 23:59
2024-01-01 00:00
1 minute, crossing month boundary
1
0
0


2024-07-15 16:45
2024-08-15 16:44
1 minute short of 1 month = 0 months
1
1
0


2024-07-15 16:45
2024-08-15 16:45
exactly 1 month
1
1
1


2024-01-31 16:45
2024-02-29 23:59
Not yet 1 month at end of short month
1
0
0


2024-01-31 16:45
2024-03-01 00:00
1 month after short month rollover to next
2
1
1


2024-02-29 16:45
2024-03-30 00:00
1 month short to long
1
1
1



Where:

DiffRaw is the original DATEDIFF() calculation.
Diff1 is the day-only adjustment calculation from above.
Diff2 is the day + time adjustment calculation from above.

See this db<>fiddle for a demo.

Added a few test cases (they all pass): https://dbfiddle.uk/rlfHMWnH

DATEDIFF() computes the number of boundaries crossed for the given segment. So Sep 2 to Aug 31 is two days (crosses day boundaries twice), but will still always be one full month because it crosses the boundary.

This function returns the count (as a signed integer value) of the specified datepart boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate.

There is no way to get it to show 0 instead of 1 if the values indeed cross the boundary, and using smaller segments like day will trip you up at odd times. The only option is to also check the day value of both inputs to decide if you may want to also subtract 1 from the final result.

This is the kind of thing you need.
SELECT DATEDIFF(month,
        CONVERT(DATE, '05/09/24', 5),
        CONVERT(DATE, '04/10/24', 5)
    ) - IIF(
        DAY(CONVERT(DATE, '05/09/24', 5)) > 
        DAY(CONVERT(DATE, '04/10/24', 5)),
        1,0
    );

This produces 0.

I would use a case expression and subtract 1 if the seconds date has a smaller day.
DECLARE @date1 DateTime
DECLARE @date2 DateTime

SET   @date1=convert(datetime,'05-09-24',5);  --Italian     5 = dd-mm-yy
SET   @date2=convert(datetime,'04-10-24',5);

SELECT  CASE WHEN  DatePart(day,@date1) < DatePart(day,@date2) 
             THEN  DATEDIFF(month, @date1, @date2) 
             ELSE  DATEDIFF(month, @date1, @date2) -1
        END as AbsoltuteDiff

fiddle

I believe the < should be <= in the above. Same starting/ending day-of-month needs no adjustment. (You also have an extra THEN.)
